# What are the domains for CORS requests from AMP?

Tags: cors, amp-html

I am new to AMP and have questions about how it uses CORS requests.

In reading up on this topic, (https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-caches-and-cors/amp-cors-requests),
and I see some info for handling requests for CORS-specific origins, namely cdn.ampproject.org and amp.cloudflare.com.

So if I owned foo.com, for example, I would need to handle foo-com.cdn.ampproject.org and foo-com.amp.cloudflare.com, and so on for any number of domains I might be implementing this on.

Are there other domains like the ampproject cdn and cloudflare that are common for the AMP project?  I have not seen too much detail on other domains but now that I see Bing is also involved with AMP I think there may be others.  I wondered if there's a list or common repository for such info?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is only three as you mentioned.

There is a JSON file for this, if you navigate to https://cdn.ampproject.org/caches.json

```
{
  "caches": [
    {
      "id": "google",
      "name": "Google AMP Cache",
      "docs": "https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/",
      "cacheDomain": "cdn.ampproject.org",
      "updateCacheApiDomainSuffix": "cdn.ampproject.org",
      "thirdPartyFrameDomainSuffix": "ampproject.net"
    },
    {
      "id": "cloudflare",
      "name": "Cloudflare AMP Cache",
      "docs": "https://amp.cloudflare.com/",
      "cacheDomain": "amp.cloudflare.com",
      "updateCacheApiDomainSuffix": "amp.cloudflare.com",
      "thirdPartyFrameDomainSuffix": "cloudflareamp.net"
    },
    {
      "id": "bing",
      "name": "Bing AMP Cache",
      "docs": "https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/bing-amp-cache-bc1c884c",
      "cacheDomain": "bing-amp.com",
      "updateCacheApiDomainSuffix": "bing-amp.com",
      "thirdPartyFrameDomainSuffix": "bing-amp.net"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see that there are 3 cache domains. In future if there is more cache domains, i expect it to be updated in this JSON file.

Comment: Thanks!  That's quite helpful!